# How do i authenticate user by email in j_security_check?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, java-ee-6, j-security-check

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm" dataSourceName="jdbc/startup" 
userTable="users" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_password" userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role_name" />  </Realm>
```

i wanted to authenticate user by email instead of username while there is no any option of email in tomcat 9 realm.

i tried to let my users login by email, but there is no functionality in j_security_check.